# ECMA 262 regex "^/" does not match input string "https://domain.herokuapp.com"

Tags: heroku, playframework, swagger, swagger-ui, playframework-2.4

I have deployed my play 2.4 API based project to heroku. On production the api is seen on `/swagger` but it also shows some error. On navigating through the error it shows the json.

```
{
    schemaValidationMessages: [{
        level: "error",
        domain: "validation",
        keyword: "pattern",
        message: "ECMA 262 regex "^/" does not match input string "https://domain.herokuapp.com "",
        schema: {
            loadingURI: "#",
            pointer: "/properties/basePath"
        },
        instance: {
            pointer: "/basePath"
        }
    }]
}
```

The dependency I have added is

```
  "io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.5.2"
```

From play prod configuration, I have [overrided](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration#Overriding-configuration-with-system-properties) swagger basepath in my procfile.

```
-Dswagger.api.basepath=https://domain.herokuapp.com
```

What could be the reason for the error and how can I remove it?

Thanks

Comment: Is "domain" the name of your Heroku app, or have you just replaced your app name with "domain"?

Comment: yes I have replaced domain with my heroku app name

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the host, the basePath is supposed to be "/". At least this solved it for me

```
  "host" : "https://domain.herokuapp.com",
  "basePath" : "/",
```